# Linear isomorphism beetween finite dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $T:(\mathbb R^n,\|.\|_1)\to (\mathbb R^n,\|.\|_2)$ be a linear isomorphism. Then clearly it is a topological isomorphism also.

> I want to show that $\|T\|\|T^{-1}\|\geq \sqrt{n}$.

Here $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|_1=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ and $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|_2=(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. I feel the inequality $\|x\|_1\leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$ will be somehow used. But I could not show it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\| T\| = \sup_{v,\ \|v\|_1=1}\ \|Tv\|_2$ ?

Comment: @ HK Lee  Yes it is true

Comment: $T^{-1}:(\mathbb R^n,\|.\|_2)\to (\mathbb R^n, \|.\|_1)$ is defined by $T^{-1}(x)=x$. Now $(2/3,2/3,\ldots,0)$ is in the unit ball of $(\mathbb R^n,\|.\|_2)$, but $\|T^{-1}(2/3,2/3,\ldots,0)\|_1=4/3>1$. Thus $\|T^{-1}\|>1$.

Comment: $\|T\|=1$. But $\|T^{-1}\|\neq 1$. $T=T^{-1}$ as vector space linear operators. But they are not same as linear operators on normed linear spaces. $\|T^{-1}\|=\sup\{\|T^{-1}(x)\|: \|x\|_2\leq 1\}$. Now for $x=(2/3,2/3,\ldots,0)$, $\|x\|_2\leq 1$. Thus $\|T^{-1}\|\geq \|T^{-1}(x)\|_1=2/3+2/3=4/3>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: THIS ANSATZ IS WRONG. SEE BELOW FOR AN ALTERNATIV ANSATZ.**

I don't think that this inequality is true for $n \geq 2$.

Let $T := \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, i.e. $$T \colon (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_1) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot\|_2), \quad x \mapsto x.$$ This an isomorphism of normed spaces with $T = T^{-1}$ and $\| T \| = 1$.

---

I think this ansatz should do the trick **[EDIT: NO IT DOESN'T]**: 
$$
\sqrt{n} = \| \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}^n} \|_{2,1} = \| T T^{-1} \|_{2,1} \leq \|T \|_{2,2} \|T^{-1}\|_{2,1} \leq \|T \|_{1,2} \|T^{-1}\|_{2,1}.
$$

In the last inequality I used that
$$
\|T\|_{2,2} \leq \|T\|_{1,2}, 
$$
as for a matrix representation $T = (a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$ we have that
$$
\|T\|_{2,2} 
= \Big( \sum_{i,j = 1}^n  a_{ij}^2 \Big)^{1/2}
= \Big( \sum_{j = 1}^n \| a_{.j} \|_2^2 \Big)^{1/2} 
\leq \Big(\sum_{j = 1}^n \| a_{.j}\|_1^2 \Big)^{1/2}
= \|T\|_{1,2}
$$

---

Apparently the relation between operator norms and entry-wise norms is particularly difficult (in fact it is NP-hard), see [here](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~nemirovs/Daureen.pdf) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.1397.pdf).

Comment: $T=T^{-1}$ in the sense of vector space linear operator only. Observe that $(2/3,2/3)$ is in the unit ball of $(\mathbb R^n,\|.\|_2)$ but 1 norm of $T^{-1}(2/3,2/3)>1$. Thus norm of $T^{-1}$ is greater than 1.

Comment: @Anupam; Sorry for the editing... Maybe this will work.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco. I was assuming that the entrywise norms come directly from considering the respective norms in domain and image. If this is wrong, of course my calculations will not make sense... See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#%22Entrywise%22_matrix_norms

Comment: Why $\|TT^-1\|_{1,2}\leq \|T\|_{2,2}\|T^{-1}\|_{2,1}$? @el_tenedor

Comment: @Anupam: I interpreted $T$ as going from $X_2$ to $X_2$ and $T^{-1}$ as going from $X_1$ to $X_2$. Then it's just an application of the submultiplicativity: $\|A B\|_{1,3} \leq \|A \|_{2,3} \|B\|_{1,2}$. I think the error in my calculations is that I assumed that $\|T\|_{1,2}$ or $\|T\|_{2,2}$ can be written as a entry-wise norm which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

i) Assume that $\| T\|=1$ (In fact, we are sufficient : If $\|
S\|=C$, then let $T=\frac{1}{C}S$ so that $\|T\|=1$. And $
 \| S\|\|S^{-1}\|>t $ iff $\|T\|\|T^{-1}\|>t$)

Assume that $\|Te_i\|_2=1$ where $e_i$ is canonical basis.

ii) If $
\|v\|_1=1$, then $\|Tv\|_2\leq 1$ so that $\|\ \|_1$-unit sphere
$S_1$ is mapped into $\|\ \|_2$-unit sphere $S_2$
.

We define a center of face of $S_1$ : $$x= \frac{1}{n}\sum_i\
\varepsilon_ie_i
$$ where $\varepsilon_i\in \{\pm 1\}$. Then from iii), there is $x$
with $$ \|Tx\|_2\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ \ast$$

If so, $$ \bigg\|T^{-1} \frac{Tx}{\| Tx\|_2 } \bigg\|_1 \geq
\sqrt{n}
$$

iii) Assume that $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n,\ \|v_i\|_2=1$ is
 independent. Prove that $$A:=\bigg\|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n
 \ \varepsilon_i v_i \bigg\|_2 \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$ for some
 $\varepsilon_i\in \{ \pm 1\}$.

Proof : If $w_i=\varepsilon_iv_i$ and $n=2$, then there
 is an obtuse triangle $w_1w_2o$ where $o$ it the origin. Hence
 $A=\cos\ \theta <\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\ \frac{\pi}{4}<\theta$.

We will use an induction. Assume that $\bigg\| W:=
 \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ w_i}{n-1}
\bigg\|_2\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}$

Assume that $$ w_n=w_\perp +w
$$ is orthogonal decomposition where $w_\perp \perp (
w_1,\cdots, w_{n-1})$.

Then \begin{align*}&\ \ \ \bigg\| \frac{ (n-1)W +w_\perp +w
}{n}\bigg\|_2^2
\\&=\frac{ \| w_\perp\|_2^2 }{n^2} +
 \frac{ \|w\|_2^2 + (n-1)^2\|W\|_2^2}{n^2} +
 2\ \frac{n-1}{n}\ W\cdot w \\&
 \leq  2\ \frac{n-1}{n}\ W\cdot w + \frac{1}{n} \end{align*}

Since we can use $-w_n$, then the proof is followed.

Remark : In the above, it holds for $
 \|v_i\|_2\leq 1$.